# C# Given a number get value at that level deep in a nest of list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Apologies for the title I could not think of how to say it clearly

Given the classes below

```c#
[System.Serializable]
public class EnemyData
{
    public EnemyType EnemyType;
    public float Speed = 0.25f;
    public float SpeedMultiplier;
    public Material Material;
    public int Hitpoints;
    public List<DeathSpawn> DeathSpawns;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class DeathSpawn
{
    public EnemyType EnemyType;
    public int Amount;
}

public class EnemyDefinitions: MonoSingleton<EnemyDefinitions>
{
    public List<EnemyData> EnemyData = new List<EnemyData>();
}
```

Let say we have an enemy Enemy1

Enemy1 has no DeathSpawns so when he dies he just dies

Enemy2 has 1 DeathSpawn and spawns Enemy1

So

`Enemy1 -> Death`

`Enemy2 -> Enemy1 -> Death`

`Enemy3 -> Enemy2 -> Enemy1 -> Death`

So if all enemys have 1 health

Given that something does 2 damage to Enemy3 it should go

`Enemy3 -> Enemy1 -> Death`

Or if something does 2 damage to Enemy2

`Enemy2 -> Death`

This is the code I am currently using

```c#
if (dmg > 0)
    {
      EnemyData enemy_data = EnemyDefinitions.Instance.EnemyData.Find(c => c.EnemyType == 
    enemy_type);
      if (enemy_data.DeathSpawns.Count > 0)
      {
      
      }
      else
      {
        return;
      }
    }
```

So whats happening here is first im checking if there was extra damage and if there is I am checking to see if the current enemy has any death spawns if not we simply return;

Where I am a bit lost is how do i say in the if statement if we have DeathSpawns getting the right DeathSpawn based on the provided damage. I have tried several different iterations of code that make no sense to me and I cannot seem to wrap my head around this

EDIT:

I though I should also add that it is possible for a enemy to have different spawns for instance

`Enemy5 -> x2 Enemy3`

`Enemy3 -> Enemy2 -> Enemy1 -> Death`

In this scenario what should have lets say Enemy5 has 1 health and it receives 2 dmg

`Enemy5 -> x1 Enemy3 x1 Enemy2`

`Enemy3 -> Enemy2 -> Enemy1 -> Death`

`Enemy2 -> Enemy1 -> Death`

Edit:

This is currently what my OnDeath function is looking like and it does not work it always defaults to "will not spawn" I just cant seem to wrap my head around the right logic to use here

```c#
public override void OnDeath(int dmg)
    {
        foreach(DeathSpawn ds in death_spawns)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < ds.amount; i++)
            {
                bool will_spawn = false;
                EnemyType spawn_type = EnemyType.White;
                EnemyType new_enemy_type = ds.enemy_type;

                for(int d = 0; d <= dmg; d++)
                {
                    Debug.Log($"for damage entered {d}");
                    EnemyData enemy_data = EnemyDefinitions.Instance.EnemyData.Find(c => c.EnemyType == new_enemy_type);

                    if(enemy_data.DeathSpawns.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (d != dmg)
                        {
                            new_enemy_type = enemy_data.DeathSpawns[0].enemy_type;
                        }

                        if (d == dmg)
                        {
                            spawn_type = enemy_data.DeathSpawns[0].enemy_type;
                            will_spawn = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Will not spawn");
                        will_spawn = false;
                    }
                }

                if (will_spawn)
                {
                    Debug.Log($"Will spawn Enemy Type: {spawn_type.ToString()}");
                    SpawnManager.Instance.Spawn(spawn_type, this.transform, this.gameObject.GetComponent<AIMotor>().GetDestination(), 0);
                }
            }
        }

        LevelManager.Instance.resources += max_hitpoint;
        UIManager.Instance.DrawBuildResource();
        SpawnManager.Instance.DestroyEnemy(this.gameObject);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the spawns working? And are just stuck on passing remaining damage down. What specifically are you stuck on

Comment: @BugFinder Yes the spawns are working I am stuck on passing the damage down

Comment: So. There must be some health component or such. When taking health and dying and spawning send the remaining damage not used to the new spawn. As a starting point.

Comment: @BugFinder yes, might not be the most efficient way, but I would go the same way for starters and simply apply remaining damage to the new spawn. Then that new spawn itself is destroyed again and spawns it next type -> again apply the remaining damage to that one. Go on until either the damage reaches `0` or the enemy is dead

Comment: @BugFinder I posted an update with what my current OnDeath method looks like in its current non-working state

Comment: Well you had spawns working so go back to that. All you needed to add was to send the remaining damage to the one you just spawned

Comment: @BugFinder Went back to that and just passed down the damage to the children surprisingly it runs quite well I really thought that it would lag tremendously or cause some weird graphical glitch but it happens so quick it looks great! It adds another bug for instance if the Enemy has more then one death spawn then the damage is passed down to both children which is undesirable but can easily be fixed